# Creating a Yahtzee Game and have trouble with Re-Roller(C++)

Tags: c++

I am currently having trouble getting my re-roller to work 100% of the time correctly. Sometimes it acts right and only changes what i select but other times it seems to have a mind of its own. Here is some snippets from my code.

```
  Int main()
  ...
  while (counter<13){
        cout<< playName << " please roll the dice."<<endl;
        system("pause");
        roll();
        reRoll();
        reRoll();
        score();}



  void reRoll(){
cout<< playName << " please select which dice you would like to re-roll by entering
   a y or n."<<endl;
cout<< "Would you like to re-roll die 1?";
cin>>dieOne;
cout<< "Would you like to re-roll die 2?";
cin>>dieTwo;
cout<< "Would you like to re-roll die 3?";
cin>>dieThree;
cout<< "Would you like to re-roll die 4?";
cin>>dieFour;
cout<< "Would you like to re-roll die 5?";
cin>>dieFive;

srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
const int dice = 6;
int die[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

if (dieOne=="y"){
    int dice1Roll = (rand() % dice);
    currentDice[0] = die[dice1Roll];}
if (dieOne!="y"){}
if (dieTwo=="y"){
    int dice2Roll = (rand() % dice);
    currentDice[1] = die[dice2Roll];}
if (dieTwo!="y"){}
if (dieThree=="y"){
    int dice3Roll = (rand() % dice);
    currentDice[2] = die[dice3Roll];}
if (dieThree!="y"){}
if (dieFour=="y"){
    int dice4Roll = (rand() % dice);
    currentDice[3] = die[dice4Roll];}
if (dieFour!="y"){}
if (dieFive=="y"){
    int dice5Roll = (rand() % dice);
    currentDice[4] = die[dice5Roll];}
if (dieFive!="y"){}
cout<<playName<<"'s die are now "<<currentDice[0]<<" "<<currentDice[1]<<" "
    <<currentDice[2]<<" "<<currentDice[3]<<" "<<currentDice[4]<<endl;}
```

Comment: Why do you have the if(dieOne!="y"){} lines?

Comment: what does it do when it "has a mind of its own"?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order for us to help you in a timely manner, please provide an example run, including all of the input and output.

Comment: Yeah I was going to add a picture but I'm not 10 rep yet. Anyways when it has a mind of its own it either changes all 5 die no matter what the input is or randomly chooses which of the five to change.

Comment: Here is an example of what happens when I run the program. The last re-roll is where the error occurs.                                            Hello and welcome to Yahtzee.
Please enter the number of players: 2
Player 1, please input your name: mat
mat please roll the dice.
Press any key to continue . . .
Rolling
mat rolled a 4 4 2 6 3
mat please select which dice you would like to re-roll by entering a y or n.
Would you like to re-roll die 1?n
Would you like to re-roll die 2?n
Would you like to re-roll die 3?n
Would you like to re-roll die 4?y
Would you like to re-roll die 5?y

Comment: and then the error arises where the code takes a sharp left turn and outputs this:
mat rolled a 5 5 1 1 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call srand each time before you use the rand function. Simply calling it once in main is enough for whatever you are doing:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void) {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    while(...) {}
    return 0
}
```

Also if you are trying to roll a number between 1 and 6, your roller should be in the form:

```
int dice1Roll = (rand() % dice) + 1;
```

Comment: Useful but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't really ask a question. I just made some observations and pointed them out to you. For example how did you declare die[One, Two, Three, Four, Five] are they string, char, or char *? Depending on what variable type they are, this might contribute to what problem you are experiencing